# How can i use template specialization within a non-templated class? c++

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++

I have a class that is not a templated class, I need to add a function to this class that is a template function. The problem is that I call a function in the class that requires a string as the parameter, so I need to make a specialized version of this template so I can call this function only if the parameter is a `const char*` or make a conditional check inside the function to only make a call to the function if the parameter is a `const char*` but that does not seem to work either. Any help would be appreciated!

```
template<class myType> __declspec(nothrow)
std::string GetStrVal(int row, int col, myType default) {

    try {
        CheckColumnType(col, String);
    }
    catch(DatatableException e){
        return default;
    }
    return this->m_rows[row][col];
}

template<class myType> 
std::string GetStrVal(int row, const char* col, myType default) {

    unsigned int columnIndex = this->GetColumnIndex(col);
    return GetStrVal(row,columnIndex, default);
}
```

`GetColumnIndex()` only takes a `const char*`.

Comment: The signature are different so you don't have a need for template specialization.

Comment: Does the compiler really accept the keyword `default` as an identifier (please don't tell me that is your actual error, since otherwise your code looks reasonable, at least regarding validity)? Or can it be that the compiler cannot decide between converting the `unsigned int columnIndex` into an `int` or a `const char*` (`int` should have priority, but I'm not sure about that). Also keep in mind that currently `GetStrVal(row, NULL, default)` will call the `int`-version (or maybe it cannot decide, too?), which might not be expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to specialize anything; you can just provide an overload or two:

```
    template<class myType> __declspec(nothrow)
    std::string GetStrVal(int row, int col, myType default);  // template

    __declspec(nothrow)
    std::string GetStrVal(int row, int col, std::string default); // overload

    __declspec(nothrow)
    std::string GetStrVal(int row, int col, const char *default); // overload
```

Comment: He wants to specialize for `col`, not for the templated parameter. But still overloading is the correct approach.